# Trouble comparing hex values in COBOL

Tags: compare, cobol, gnucobol

I'm trying to compare two hex values as in the code at the bottom. I was expecting that the `IF` statement, where I compare field `A` and field `WS-FLD-X`, would result in true, but it doesn't do it.

In other words, when I move `12` to `WS-FLD-A`, the value in `WS-FLD-X` should be stored as `X'0C'`, right? This value is expected to be the same value in field `A`. Comparing the two values should result in true, however this is not happening.

Why? What is the difference between the value held in field `A` and the value in `WS-FLD-X`?

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 FF.
    05  A  PIC XX.
    05  B  PIC XXXXXX.
01 F.
    05 WS-FLD PIC S9(4) COMP.
    05 WS-FLD-X REDEFINES WS-FLD PIC XX.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    DISPLAY 'Hello, world' UPON CONSOLE.

    MOVE X'0C' TO A.
    MOVE "SOME TEXT" TO B.
    DISPLAY FF UPON CONSOLE.

    MOVE 12 TO WS-FLD
    DISPLAY "HEX OF 12 IS:" WS-FLD-X UPON CONSOLE.
    IF WS-FLD-X = A THEN DISPLAY "SAME" UPON CONSOLE END-IF.
```

[Code in web IDE](http://tpcg.io/BNYZFfpX)

Comment: I'm not sure what actual question this post has so I can't provide the answer (you may want to elaborate). What I can say:
`A` is an alphanumeric field, and therefore will be right-filled with a space, `WS-FLD` is a numeric one so will be left-filled with zero (and `DISPLAY`ing hex null will commonly not work).

Comment: @SimonSobisch, thank you for looking at the question. I have added further explanation to the question's body. Pls note that field A contains hexadecimal value X'0C' not right filled with space.

Comment: @NoChance - By rule (for alphanumeric `MOVE`), `A`  will contain `X'0C20'` (ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

You moved a single byte to a 2 byte field so the move padded to the right with a space (per Simon).

```
MOVE X'0C' TO A.    // (A now contains x'0C20' which is not 12)
```

You'd need to move both bytes to keep the value of the number intact.

```
MOVE x'000C' TO A
```

The program now displays 'SAME'.

Comment: Excellent Jim. One more question please, I can create a new question for it if you wish, How to read the hex value 000C from a file and do the above move?

Comment: @NoChance - It is better to ask a new question supplying a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as before. Specifically, include the `SELECT` statement and `FD` that describes the file and its record composition. The `PROCEDURE DIVISION` need not do more than `OPEN`, `READ`, and `CLOSE` the file.

Comment: @RickSmith, I did what you have suggested - Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595834/how-to-convert-a-literal-to-hex-value